# Java Homework Assignment Linked List

Tags: java

Thank you for everyone who got me on my feet. However, My cutSplice method is inefficient. I need to be able to modify it easy so that i can do the reverse method.

---

developing a single Java class (LinkedDnaStrand) that uses a linked list of nodes to represent a strand of DNA that supports splicing.  Each node in the list will contain a string of one or more nucleotides (A, C, G, or T).  The class will be responsible for operations such as append() and cutSplice(), which model real-world restriction enzyme processing.

### EX. tt will be replaced with cat. (Better LinkedDnaStrandTester)

```
package dnasplicing;

public class DnaSequenceNode {
public String dnaSequence;
public DnaSequenceNode previous;
public DnaSequenceNode next;


public DnaSequenceNode(String initialDnaSequence) {
    dnaSequence = initialDnaSequence;
}
}
```

---

```
package dnasplicing;

public class LinkedDnaStrand implements DnaStrand {

int nodeCount = 0;

int appendCount = 0;

long nucleotideCount = 0;

String sequenceString;

DnaSequenceNode cursor, head, tail;


public LinkedDnaStrand(String dnaSequence) {

    DnaSequenceNode newNode = new DnaSequenceNode(dnaSequence);
    head = newNode;
    cursor = head;
    tail = head;
    head.previous = null;
    tail.previous = null;
    sequenceString = dnaSequence;
    nodeCount++;


}


    public String toString() {

    String result = "";
    DnaSequenceNode n = head;
    while (n != null) {
        result += n.dnaSequence;
        n = n.next;
    }
    return result;

}


@Override
public long getNucleotideCount() {

    nucleotideCount = sequenceString.length();
    return nucleotideCount;

}


@Override
public void append(String dnaSequence) {

    if (dnaSequence != null && dnaSequence.length() > 0) {
        tail.next = new DnaSequenceNode(dnaSequence);
        tail.next.previous = tail;
        tail = tail.next;
        sequenceString += dnaSequence;
        appendCount++;
        nodeCount++;


    }


}


@Override
public DnaStrand cutSplice(String enzyme, String splicee) {


    boolean frontSplice = false;
    boolean backSplice = false;

    if (sequenceString.startsWith(enzyme)) {
        frontSplice = true;
    }
    if (sequenceString.endsWith(enzyme)) {
        backSplice = true;
    }

    String[] dnaParts = sequenceString.split(enzyme);
    LinkedDnaStrand newLinkedStrand = null;

    if (frontSplice == true) {
        newLinkedStrand = new LinkedDnaStrand(splicee);
        // newLinkedStrand.append(dnaParts[0]);

        for (int i = 1; i < dnaParts.length; i++) {
            newLinkedStrand.append(dnaParts[i]);
            if (i < dnaParts.length - 1) {
                newLinkedStrand.append(splicee);
            }
        }
    } else {
        newLinkedStrand = new LinkedDnaStrand(dnaParts[0]);
        for (int index = 1; index < dnaParts.length; index++) {
            newLinkedStrand.append(splicee);
            newLinkedStrand.append(dnaParts[index]);
        }
    }

    if (backSplice == true) {
        newLinkedStrand.append(splicee);
    }

    // sequenceString = newLinkedStrand.toString();


    return newLinkedStrand;

}


@Override
public DnaStrand createReversedDnaStrand() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}


@Override
public int getAppendCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return appendCount;
}


@Override
public DnaSequenceNode getFirstNode() {
    return head;
}


@Override
public int getNodeCount() {
    return nodeCount;
}

}
```

---

```
package dnasplicing;

public interface DnaStrand {

/**
 * NOTE: Your LinkedDnaStrand class must have a constructor that takes one parameter: String dnaSequence. When the
 * constructor completes, your linked list should have just one node, and it should contain the passed-in
 * dnaSequence. For example, if the following line of code was executed:
 * 
 * LinkedDnaStrand strand = new LinkedDnaStrand("GATTACA");
 * 
 * Then strand's linked list should look something like (previous pointers not shown):
 * 
 * first -> "GATTACA" -> null
 * 
 * The first line of this constructor should look like:
 * 
 * public LinkedDnaStrand(String dnaSequence) {
 */

/**
 * @return The entire DNA sequence represented by this DnaStrand.
 */
public String toString();


/**
 * Returns the number of nucleotides in this strand.
 * 
 * @return the number of base-pairs in this strand
 */
public long getNucleotideCount();


/**
 * Appends the given dnaSequence on to the end of this DnaStrand. appendCount is incremented. Note: If this
 * DnaStrand is empty, append() should just do the same thing as the constructor. In this special case, appendCount
 * is not incremented.
 * 
 * @param dnaSequence
 *            is the DNA string to append
 */
public void append(String dnaSequence);


/**
 * This method creates a <bold>new</bold> DnaStrand that is a clone of the current DnaStrand, but with every
 * instance of enzyme replaced by splicee. For example, if the LinkedDnaStrand is instantiated with "TTGATCC", and
 * cutSplice("GAT", "TTAAGG") is called, then the linked list should become something like (previous pointers not
 * shown):
 * 
 * first -> "TT" -> "TTAAGG" -> "CC" -> null
 * 
 * <b>NOTE</b>: This method will only be called when the linke list has just one node, and it will only be called
 * once for a DnaStrand. This means that you do not need to worry about searching for enzyme matches across node
 * boundaries.
 * 
 * @param enzyme
 *            is the DNA sequence to search for in this DnaStrand.
 * 
 * @param splicee
 *            is the DNA sequence to append in place of the enzyme in the returned DnaStrand
 * 
 * @return A <bold>new</bold> strand leaving the original strand unchanged.
 */
public DnaStrand cutSplice(String enzyme, String splicee);


/**
 * Returns a <bold>new</bold> DnaStrand that is the reverse of this strand, e.g., if this DnaStrand contains "CGAT",
 * then the returned DnaStrand should contain "TAGC".
 * 
 * @return A <bold>new</bold> strand containing a reversed DNA sequence.
 */
public DnaStrand createReversedDnaStrand();


/**
 * 
 * @return The number of times that the DnaStrand has been appended via a call to append() or during the cutSplice()
 *         operation. Note that the very first time that a DnaStrand is given a DNA sequence is not to be counted as
 *         an append.
 */
public int getAppendCount();


/**
 * This is a utility method that allows the outside world direct access to the nodes in the linked list.
 * 
 * @return The first DnaSequenceNode in the linked list of nodes.
 */
public DnaSequenceNode getFirstNode();


/**
 * This is a utility method that allows the outside world to determine the number of nodes in the linked list.
 * 
 * @return
 */
public int getNodeCount();

}
```

---

```
package sbccunittest;

import static java.lang.Math.*;
import static java.lang.System.*;
import static org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.io.*;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.*;
import org.junit.*;

import dnasplicing.*;

// Updated 25-Feb-2016 at 6:10pm
public class LinkedDnaStrandTester {

static String ecoliSmall = "AGCTTTTCATTAGCCCGCAGGCAGCCCCACACCCGCCGCCTCCTGCACCGAGAGAGATGGAATAAAGCCCTTGAACCAGC";

static String ecor1 = "GAATTC"; // restriction enzyme

public static int totalScore = 0;

public static int extraCredit = 0;

public static InputStream defaultSystemIn;

public static PrintStream defaultSystemOut;

public static PrintStream defaultSystemErr;

public static String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");



public void testCutSplice() {
    String enzyme = "GAT";
    String splicee = "TTAAGG";
    String[] strands = { "TTGATCC", "TCGATCTGATTTCCGATCC", "GATCTGATCTGAT" };
    String[][] recombinants = { { "TT", "TTAAGG", "CC" },
            { "TC", "TTAAGG", "CT", "TTAAGG", "TTCC", "TTAAGG", "CC" },
            { "TTAAGG", "CT", "TTAAGG", "CT", "TTAAGG" } };

    for (int ndx = 0; ndx < strands.length; ndx++) {
        LinkedDnaStrand linkedStrand = new LinkedDnaStrand(strands[ndx]);

        DnaStrand newlinkedStrand = linkedStrand.cutSplice(enzyme, splicee);
        assertEquals("cutSplice(" + enzyme + ", " + splicee + ") failed at ndx = " + ndx, join(recombinants[ndx]),
                newlinkedStrand.toString());
        assertEquals("Append counts didn't match for ndx = " + ndx, recombinants[ndx].length - 1,
                newlinkedStrand.getAppendCount());

        // Verify that each node contains the correct DNA sequence
        DnaSequenceNode node = newlinkedStrand.getFirstNode();
        for (int nodeNdx = 0; nodeNdx < recombinants.length; nodeNdx++) {
            assertNotNull("For strand " + ndx + ", there is no node at position " + nodeNdx, node);
            assertEquals("For strand " + ndx + ", the sequences don't match at position " + nodeNdx,
                    recombinants[ndx][nodeNdx], node.dnaSequence);
            node = node.next;
        }

    }
    totalScore += 5;

}


/**
 * Verifies that LinkedDnaStrand can model a cut and splice of (part of) the E Coli sequence using the ECoR1
 * restriction enzyme and insulin as a splicee.
 */
@Test
public void testSpliceInsulinIntoEcoli() {

    for (int testNumber = 1; testNumber <= 5; testNumber++) {
        int startNdx = (int) (random() * 0.33 * ecoliSmall.length()); // Somewhere in the
                                                                        // first third
        int endNdx = ecoliSmall.length() - 1 - (int) (random() * 0.33 * ecoliSmall.length());
        String ecoliPart = ecoliSmall.substring(startNdx, endNdx);
        LinkedDnaStrand linkedStrand = new LinkedDnaStrand(ecoliPart);
        SimpleDnaStrand simpleStrand = new SimpleDnaStrand(ecoliPart);

        DnaStrand newL = linkedStrand.cutSplice(ecor1, insulin);
        DnaStrand newS = simpleStrand.cutSplice(ecor1, insulin);

        assertEquals(newS.toString(), newL.toString());
        assertEquals(newS.getAppendCount(), newL.getAppendCount());
        assertEquals(newS.getAppendCount(), newL.getNodeCount() - 1);

        // Verify that the nodes exist
        DnaSequenceNode node = newL.getFirstNode();
        for (int ndx = 0; ndx < newL.getNodeCount(); ndx++) {
            assertNotNull("There is no node at position " + ndx, node);
            node = node.next;
        }
    }
    totalScore += 10;
}


/**
 * Verifies that LinkedDnaStrand can model a cut and splice efficiently.
 */
@Test
public void testSplicingTime() {
    // First verify that the LinkedDnaStrand cutSplice works
    int startNdx = (int) (random() * 0.33 * ecoliSmall.length()); // Somewhere in the first
                                                                    // third
    int endNdx = ecoliSmall.length() - 1 - (int) (random() * 0.33 * ecoliSmall.length());
    String ecoliPart = ecoliSmall.substring(startNdx, endNdx);
    LinkedDnaStrand linkedStrand = new LinkedDnaStrand(ecoliPart);
    SimpleDnaStrand simpleStrand = new SimpleDnaStrand(ecoliPart);

    String splicee = createRandomDnaSequence(1024 * 1024, 1024 * 1024);

    DnaStrand newL = linkedStrand.cutSplice(ecor1, splicee);
    DnaStrand newS = simpleStrand.cutSplice(ecor1, splicee);

    assertEquals(newS.toString(), newL.toString());
    assertEquals(newS.getAppendCount(), newL.getAppendCount());

    // Now verify that it can cut and splice N times in less than T seconds
    int numSplicings = 200;
    double maxTime = 2.0;

    double start = nanoTime();

    for (int i = 0; i < numSplicings; i++)
        newL = linkedStrand.cutSplice(ecor1, splicee);

    double end = nanoTime();
    double time = ((end - start) / 1e9);

    // out.println("Time = " + time);
    assertTrue("Time limit of " + maxTime + " seconds exceeded.  Time to splice " + numSplicings + " times was "
            + time + " seconds.", time <= maxTime);
    totalScore += 5;
}


/**
 * Verifies that LinkedDnaStrand can create a new, reversed LinkedDnaStrand.
 */
@Test
public void testReverse() {
    String dnaSequence = createRandomDnaSequence(50, 100);
    String dnaToAppend = createRandomDnaSequence(5, 10);
    int numTimesToAppend = (int) (random() * 10);
    LinkedDnaStrand linkedStrand = new LinkedDnaStrand(dnaSequence);
    SimpleDnaStrand simpleStrand = new SimpleDnaStrand(dnaSequence);

    for (int ndx = 0; ndx < numTimesToAppend; ndx++) {
        linkedStrand.append(dnaToAppend);
        simpleStrand.append(dnaToAppend);
    }

    assertEquals(simpleStrand.toString(), linkedStrand.toString());
    assertEquals(numTimesToAppend + 1, linkedStrand.getNodeCount());

    LinkedDnaStrand rl = (LinkedDnaStrand) linkedStrand.createReversedDnaStrand();

    // Verify that the original linked strand wasn't changed
    DnaSequenceNode node = linkedStrand.getFirstNode();
    int nodeNdx = 0;
    while (node != null) {
        assertEquals("Sequences don't match at node index " + nodeNdx, nodeNdx == 0 ? dnaSequence : dnaToAppend,
                node.dnaSequence);
        node = node.next;
        nodeNdx++;
    }

    // Verify that the new strand string is reversed
    assertEquals(simpleStrand.createReversedDnaStrand().toString(), rl.toString());
    totalScore += 10;

    // If the new strand has a reverse order of nodes and sequences within each node, give extra
    // credit
    int numNodes = linkedStrand.getNodeCount();
    if (numNodes == rl.getNodeCount()) {
        // Build array of reversed dna strings from original LinkedDnaStrand. Start at end of
        // array and move toward
        // start
        node = linkedStrand.getFirstNode();
        String[] reversedDnaSequences = new String[linkedStrand.getNodeCount()];
        nodeNdx = numNodes - 1;
        while (node != null) {
            reversedDnaSequences[nodeNdx] = reverse(node.dnaSequence);
            node = node.next;
            nodeNdx--;
        }

        // Verify that the reversed list's nodes contain the same data as in the array
        node = rl.getFirstNode();
        nodeNdx = 0;
        while (node != null) {
            if (!node.dnaSequence.equals(reversedDnaSequences[nodeNdx]))
                break;
            node = node.next;
            nodeNdx++;
        }
        if (nodeNdx == linkedStrand.getNodeCount())
            extraCredit += 5;
    }

}


private String[] createRandomDnaSequences(int numDnaSequences, int minLength, int maxLength) {
    String[] dnaSequences = new String[numDnaSequences];
    for (int ndx = 0; ndx < numDnaSequences; ndx++)
        dnaSequences[ndx] = createRandomDnaSequence(minLength, maxLength);
    return dnaSequences;
}


private String createRandomDnaSequence(int minLength, int maxLength) {
    return RandomStringUtils.random((int) (random() * (maxLength - minLength) + minLength), "ACGT");
}


@BeforeClass
public static void beforeTesting() throws Exception {
    totalScore = 0;
    extraCredit = 0;
}


@AfterClass
public static void afterTesting() {
    out.println("Estimated score (w/o late penalties, etc.) = " + totalScore);
    out.println("Estimated extra credit (assuming on time submission) = " + extraCredit);
}


@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    defaultSystemIn = System.in;
    defaultSystemOut = System.out;
    defaultSystemErr = System.err;
}


@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    System.setIn(defaultSystemIn);
    System.setOut(defaultSystemOut);
    System.setErr(defaultSystemErr);
}


public void sendToStdinOfTestee(String message) {
    System.setIn(new ByteArrayInputStream(message.getBytes()));
}

}
```

---

Comment: Do you only want help with understanding toString()?

Comment: From your current input it is **very** hard to understand what exactly your problem is; and we are **not** here to do your homework for you!

Comment: I can explain to you what you don't understand but like @GhostCat said I can't write the code for you

Answer (score -1):

So I don't have some of the classes like the node class you are using so I cannot write the actual code but i will give you some pseudo code.

```
public String toString(){
    String result = "";
    Node n = start;
    while(n != null){
       string += n.data;
    }
    return result;
}

public long getNucleotideCount() {
    long result = 0;
    Node n = start;
    while(n != null){
       result += n.data.length();
    }
    return result;
}


public void append(String dnaSequence) {
    end.next = new Node(dnaSequence);
    end = end.next;
    appendCount++;
}

public DnaStrand cutSplice(String enzyme, String splice) {
// For this I think it would be best to assemble into string then use replace
    Node n =  start;
    String result = "";
    while(n != null){
      result += n.data;
    }
    result = result.replace(enzyme, splice)
    return new DnaStrand(result);
}
```

The reverse method would be similar to cutSplice. Assemble to string, manipulate, then return new strand. If you need more help LMK.